# How to schedule crontrigger to run on certain days of the week?

Tags: java, cron, schedule, crontrigger

I have a job to execute on Saturday and Sunday, but not on weekdays. This is how I schedule it:

```
myTriggerBuilder.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 0 * * ?")).build();
```

The scheduler in use is Quartz.

This will run at 00:00:00 server time each day. However, I would like to make it work only on Saturday and Sunday, however, in American calendars Saturday is the end of the week and Sunday is the start of the week. I have been searching the [docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html) for an example or description which explains how can I specify certain days of the week rather than intervals, but the docs either does not provide that information, or I have missed it. I have tried it this way:

```
myTriggerBuilder.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 0 * * SAT,SUN")).build();
```

However, the whole thing crashed:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '0 0 0 * * SAT,SUN' is
> invalid.

Is there a way to express what I want, that is, to tell the scheduler which days of the week I intend to run the job?

Comment: You need to tag which scheduler you are using or mention it in your question, from the link it's Quartz, but you didn't mention it. Here the docs http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this?

```
0 0 0 ? * SUN,SAT *
```

Refer: [This](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

Comment: Thanks, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try expression like (for example you want to start 8:05 Sunday 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday)

```
5 8 * * 0,6
```

You can check this link

https://crontab.guru/every-weekend

Comment: in quartz the days of week are 1..7 not 0..6 http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html